# ADF v2 Cancel InProgress Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I can get the List of Pipelines using the following but cannot find the option to cancel the InProgress pipeline. How can i cancel pipeline that are in progress ?

```
var pf = new PipelineRunFilterParameters();
            pf.LastUpdatedAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);
            pf.LastUpdatedBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

            var pr = client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactory(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName,pf);
            foreach(var r in pr.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.PipelineName + " ... " + r.Status);

                if (r.Status == "InProgress")
                   //How do i Cancel this pipeline ?   

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a method Suspend, that will suspend a running pipeline instance. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactories.pipelineoperationsextensions.suspend?view=azure-dotnet)

Did not try it by myself through.